# InverseFourierSinTransform on Mathematica did not give a result

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, integral-transforms, fourier-analysis

I am trying to solve the linear Schrödinger equation with the Fourier transform. I have difficulty making the corresponding graph when I solve the problem numerically. Can you explain to me what is my mistake in the following code?

```
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(u\), \(^\)]\)[\[Omega]_, t_] = -((
  2 E^(-I t v \[Omega]^2) (-T0 + 
     E^(I t v \[Omega]^2)
       T0 + \[Omega] DawsonF[\[Omega]/2]))/\[Omega])

u[x_, t_] = InverseFourierSinTransform[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(u\), \(^\)]\)[\[Omega], t], \[Omega], x, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, Assumptions -> {x > 0}]
```

Then I tried to create the graph

```
T0 = 1;
Plot[Abs[u[x, t]]^2, {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

You can download the notebook of my project from [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2933433?p_p_auth=EDa2Rjm5)
[image]

---

ps. Consider using this input as more readable (edit by Nasser)

```
OverHat[u][ω_, t_] = -((2*(-T0 + E^(I*t*v*ω^2)*T0 + ω*DawsonF[ω/2]))/E^(I*t*v*ω^2)/ω)
u[x_, t_] = InverseFourierSinTransform[OverHat[u][ω, t], ω, x, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, Assumptions -> {x > 0}]
```

Comment: I think it will be better if you just post only the relevant part of your code related to using `InverseFourierSinTransform` only, which did not evaluate and that why the plot did not work. Do you need all the other definitions of ode and plot commands to show this? I do not think so. This will make your question easier to understand and more chance of getting help.

Comment: @Nasser I think now it is better

Comment: Yes, agree, much better now. But to make it even better consider posting the InputForm instead. Much more readable. See the difference  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7bba.png)  this I can read. But what you showed above due to the 2D fancy letters used which looks good in notebook but not in the post. ps. I put that in your question at the end. Free free to use it if you want, or delete it if you do not want it.

Comment: @Nasser No i like it. I will keep it

Comment: @Nasser Although it does not give me a result too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
OverHat[u][\[Omega]_, t_] = -((2*(-T0 + 
       E^(I*t*v*\[Omega]^2)*T0 + \[Omega]*DawsonF[\[Omega]/2]))/
   E^(I*t*v*\[Omega]^2)/\[Omega]) // FunctionExpand // Expand

(*-((2 T0)/\[Omega]) + (2 E^(-I t v \[Omega]^2) T0)/\[Omega] - 
E^(-(\[Omega]^2/4) - I t v \[Omega]^2) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erfi[\[Omega]/2]*)

InverseFourierSinTransform[#, \[Omega], x, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, Assumptions -> {x > 0}] & /@OverHat[u][\[Omega], t]
```

Mathematica can't compute: $\sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}\left(\frac{\omega }{2}\right) \left(-e^{-\frac{\omega ^2}{4}-i t v \omega ^2}\right)$ term.

We use identity:$$\text{erfi}\left(\frac{\omega }{2}\right)=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{2 e^{-z^2+\frac{\omega ^2}{4}} \sin (z \omega )}{\sqrt{\pi }} \, dz$$
then:

```
Integrate[InverseFourierSinTransform[
E^(-(\[Omega]^2/4) - I t v \[Omega]^2) Sqrt[\[Pi]] *(
2 E^(-z^2 + \[Omega]^2/4) Sin[z \[Omega]])/Sqrt[\[Pi]] // 
FullSimplify, \[Omega], x, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, 
Assumptions -> {x > 0, z >= 0}], {z, 0, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> x > 0]

(*ConditionalExpression[-(E^(x^2/(-1 - 
(4*I)*t*v))*Sqrt[I*t*v]*Sqrt[(I*t*v - 4*t^2*v^2)^(-1)]*Erf[Sqrt[((4*I)*t*v - 16*t^2*v^2)^(-1)]*x]), Im[1/(t*v)] > -4]*)
```

So:

$$u(x,t)=-\text{T0} \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{i t v}}\right)-e^{\frac{x^2}{-1-4 i t v}} \sqrt{i t v} \sqrt{\frac{1}{i t v-4 t^2 v^2}} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{4 i t v-16 t^2 v^2}}
   x\right)+\text{T0} \text{sgn}(x)$$

```
 u[x_, t_] = -T0 Erf[x/(2 Sqrt[I t v])] - 
 E^(x^2/(-1 - 4 I t v)) Sqrt[I t v] Sqrt[1/(I t v - 4 t^2 v^2)]
 Erf[Sqrt[1/(4 I t v - 16 t^2 v^2)] x] + T0 Sign[x]

 T0 = 1; v = 1;(*Assumed parameters *)
 Plot[Abs[u[x, 1/5]]^2, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All](*for t=1/5*)
```

[image]